# How to add a key-value to JSON data retrieved from a file?

Tags: python, json, file

I am new to Python and I am playing with JSON data. I would like to retrieve the JSON data from a file and add to that data a JSON key-value "on the fly".

That is, my `json_file` contains JSON data as-like the following:

```
{"key1": {"key1A": ["value1", "value2"], "key1B": {"key1B1": "value3"}}}
```

I would like to add the `"ADDED_KEY": "ADDED_VALUE"` key-value part to the above data so to use the following JSON in my script:

```
{"ADDED_KEY": "ADDED_VALUE", "key1": {"key1A": ["value1", "value2"], "key1B": {"key1B1": "value3"}}}
```

I am trying to write something as-like the following in order to accomplish the above:

```
import json

json_data = open(json_file)
json_decoded = json.load(json_data)

# What I have to make here?!

json_data.close()
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your `json_decoded` object is a Python dictionary; you can simply add your key to that, then re-encode and rewrite the file:

```
import json

with open(json_file) as json_file:
    json_decoded = json.load(json_file)

json_decoded['ADDED_KEY'] = 'ADDED_VALUE'

with open(json_file, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_decoded, json_file)
```

I used the open file objects as context managers here (with the `with` statement) so Python automatically closes the file when done.

Comment: Using this code I have a problem with adding new key-value. My file gets overwritten with a new key-value pair.

Comment: @MrKarma4u: the whole file is re-written, yes. The file is rewritten with the full dictionary, however, so if you are missing data it wasn't part of what was read from the file before adding the new key.

Answer (score 12):

Json returned from json.loads() behave just like native python lists/dictionaries:

```
import json

with open("your_json_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read()) #data becomes a dictionary

#do things with data here
data['ADDED_KEY'] = 'ADDED_VALUE'

#and then just write the data back on the file
with open("your_json_file.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
#I added some options for pretty printing, play around with them!
```

For more info check out [the official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html)

Answer (score 9):

You can do

```
json_decoded['ADDED_KEY'] = 'ADDED_VALUE'
```

OR

```
json_decoded.update({"ADDED_KEY":"ADDED_VALUE"})
```

which works nicely if you want to add more than one key/value pair.

Of course, you may want to check for the existence of ADDED_KEY first - depends on your needs.

AND I assume you want might want to save that data back to the file

```
json.dump(json_decoded, open(json_file,'w'))
```

Comment: How to check for the existence of ADDED_KEY?

Comment: My approach would depend on what I wanted to do if it did exist. How would you want to handle that if the key did already exist?

Comment: I would like to overwrite the existing JSON value. However, for my curiosity, I am interested even to "raise" an error if the JSON key exists and to handle the case of "nesting".