# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python, json, file, contextmanager

I am trying to open, read, modify, and close a json file using the example here:

[How to add a key-value to JSON data retrieved from a file with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111625/how-to-add-a-key-value-to-json-data-retrieved-from-a-file-with-python)

```
import os
import json

path = '/m/shared/Suyash/testdata/BIDS/sub-165/ses-1a/func'
os.chdir(path)

string_filename = "sub-165_ses-1a_task-cue_run-02_bold.json"

with open ("sub-165_ses-1a_task-cue_run-02_bold.json", "r") as jsonFile:
    json_decoded = json.load(jsonFile)

json_decoded["TaskName"] = "CUEEEE"

with open(jsonFile, 'w') as jsonFIle:
    json.dump(json_decoded,jsonFile) ######## error here that open() won't work with _io.TextIOWrapper
```

I keep getting an error at the end (with `open(jsonFile...)` that I can't use the `jsonFile` variable with `open()`. I used the exact format as the example provided in the link above so I'm not sure why it's not working. This is eventually going in a larger script so I want to stay away from hard coding/ using strings for the json file name.

Comment: When you copy code from the internet, there's no guarantee that it is actually working. You have one "with open" that works and one that doesn't work. You also have an error message telling you why the second one doesn't work. That should give you enough information to fix the problem.

Comment: Btw you made a type in `with open(jsonFile, 'w') as jsonFIle:`. There is a "I" instead of a "i" in the `as jsonFIle`.

Answer (score 11):

This Question is a bit old, but for anyone with the same issue:

You're right you can't open the jsonFile variable. Its a pointer to another file connection and open wants a string or something similar. Its worth noting that jsonFile should also be closed once you exit the 'with' block so it should not be referenced outside of that.

To answer the question though:

```
with open(jsonFile, 'w') as jsonFile:
   json.dump(json_decoded,jsonFile)
```

should be

```
with open(string_filename, 'w') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(json_decoded,jsonFile)
```

You can see  we just need to use the same string to open a new connection and then we can give it the same alias we used to read the file if we want. Personally I prefer in_file and out_file just to be explicit about my intent.

Answer (score 1):

If you come here because you are reading in a file from the command line using click and the file cannot be opened/read by `with open(click_file_obj, "r") as f`, use the `name` attribute of the _texIOwrapper object generated by click. That is,

```
with open(click_file_obj.name, "r") as f:
    file_text = f.read()
```

This worked for me.
Source: https://python-forum.io/thread-1277.html