# Write a new key to every line in a NDJSON file

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to format the data to feed into an API. The requested body asking for

```
{ userEvent: { eventType: "home-page-view", visitorId: "visitor-1", userInfo: { userId: "user-1" } } }
{ userEvent: { eventType: "home-page-view", visitorId: "visitor-2", userInfo: { userId: "user-2" } } }
{ userEvent: { eventType: "home-page-view", visitorId: "visitor-3", userInfo: { userId: "user-3" } } }
...
```

I got a query to get the required columns in BigQuery and then push the table result to GCS in the NDJSON format. However, I have no clue how to add a key `userEvent` to include the currently available results (1) during the query or (2) after storing the NDJSON file in GCS. Given that the expected number of rows will be roughly one million, I wonder what the most efficient solution to this as I'd like to avoid a for loop to go through each line...

This is what I have now:

```
# get the BigQuery result and store in the "results" variable
query_job = bq_client.query(query, job_config=job_config, location="US")
results = query_job.result() #<google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator at 0x148728310>

# The current NDJSON file in GCS
{"eventType":"home-page-view","visitorId":"13245","userInfo":{"userId":"11111"}
{"eventType":"home-page-view","visitorId":"56789","userInfo":{"userId":"22222"}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111625/how-to-add-a-key-value-to-json-data-retrieved-from-a-file This is the solution to add key:value pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Anita, you can refer to the below sample code mentioned in this stack [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111625/how-to-add-a-key-value-to-json-data-retrieved-from-a-file) to add the key:value pair.

```
import json

with open(json_file) as json_file:
    json_decoded = json.load(json_file)

json_decoded['KEY'] = 'VALUE'

with open(json_file, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_decoded, json_file)
```

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.